# PHP NetSuite API - get Customer records by internalID range

Tags: php, api, netsuite, records

I need to sync Customers from NetSuite to another system and would like to search Customers by internalId range, using the PHP library for the API.  Given that the internalId's are autoincrement fields, I would only need Customers with internalId greater than the highest ID in the external system.

Is there a way to do this?  If so, how?

I've currently only been able to iterate over ALL records, using the SearchRequest and SearchMoreWithIdRequest.  A slight optimization I can do with this is to iterate over the pages in reverse order to avoid pulling too much duplicate data, but would prefer to filter by internalId (greater-than) if possible.

Thanks

---

here is existing code

```
///  initial search

$search = new CustomerSearchBasic();

$request = new SearchRequest();
$request->searchRecord = $search;

$searchResponse = $service->search($request);

// cache the search ID because we're gonna need to re-search, with pagination, using this id
$searchId = $searchResponse->searchResult->searchId;
$totalRecords = $searchResponse->searchResult->totalRecords;

// process the results
process_response($searchResponse);


// get subsequent pages
for ($page = 2; $page < ceil($totalRecords / $pageSize); $page++) {
    echo "[page: $page]  ...   searchId: '$searchId'" . PHP_EOL;
    if (!$searchId) continue;

    $request = new SearchMoreWithIdRequest();
    $request->searchId = $searchId;
    $request->pageIndex = $page;
    $searchResponse = $service->searchMoreWithId($request);

    // process the results
    process_response($searchResponse);
}

function process_response($searchResponse) { ... }
```

Comment: Please include some code of what you have tried.

Comment: added existing code.  using CustomerSearchBasic with no criteria added, to get ALL records.  would like to add criteria to filter by internalId, but only a limited range, i.e. greater than some integer X

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to build the search within the NetSuite GUI, then basically load that saved search by internal ID from your PHP code. Not elegant, but it can work.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @zeros-and-ones no. customer went away before we dug deep enough to fix it